Application Insight Alert Rule: How to include additional information?
At my job, I am currently working on setting up application insight, with alert rules, so we can manage exceptions better in our applications. I created a "custom log search" signal, with the following query:
let targetOperationName = "TestWarning";
traces
| where operation_Name == targetOperationName

And configured it to check every minute (For testing) if the number of received logs surpasses 10. When it does, I receive a mail. Though I am not satisfied with the information provided in the mail. I would like additional information for the alert, from the log columns, such as message, customDimensions and operation_Name.
Is this possible?
I've looked at the advanced options -> custom properties, but I am uncertain I can retrieve the information I wish from there.

The alert email should be simple enough and basically say: Hey something happened. But the email includes a link to the Azure portal and allow you to run the alert query, which includes all the info you need.

That is true, but I do think it would be much more more valuable if the actual exception was in the email, as it does require a couple of click afterwards to find out what is wrong. The email is automatically made into a ticket, so would be nice to know the issue before having to go to azure.

You might be able to customize alert notifications by using Logic Apps, but considering the cost (create and configure Log Apps) vs the benefit (custom email alerts) it might not be worth the effort.

Thanks, i'll check it out. Sounds like it's possible to do in the alert rule configurations.


Application Insight Alert Rule: How to include additional information?

I do agree with @Rui Jarimba, that you can use Logic apps for this and below is the design which works for me:

then:

Later in true or false condition you can customise your alert as you want as below:

Output:



Would this work together with Alerts, or can you in Logic Apps send an email based on conditions such as "This query count is 10 in the last 30 minutes, therefor send email"?

Yeah you can set the recurrence for 30 min in trigger and then check the count and is 10 and send an email

If you are only wanting to include the dimensions, then advanced options and selecting as many dimension details you want would work.
to get to as many dimension flavors, expand the time stamp run time of yoru query when setting up the dimensions. Once they are set, you can then reduce the time stamp to 5m granularity.
(| where timestamp > ago(72h) or to more #of days)
Reason to expand the time when setting up is only to capture more flavors/dimensions from the past occurences.
in my opinion, Logic app is probably more needed if you want to build the dynamic URL to the failure page or if you want to trigger alerts from diff appis from diff RGs.
Just a thought!
